# How can I set minimum length of edittext and set input type to have a Uppercase letter or a number?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

How can I set minimum length of `EditText` and set input type to have a `Uppercase` letter or a number. I`m making a registration page and I need this for password`EditText`.

Answer (score 1):

for uppercase letter you can use `android:textAllCaps="true"` and for numberinput use `android:inputType="numberPassword"`

Answer (score -1):

You can use sample edittext component

```
 <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:minLength="6"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:inputType="numberPassword"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: And after making this edittext password will be with min 6 caract. and letters + numbers or uppercase letter + lowercase letter ?

Comment: @mertaksu you cant use same attribute thrice

Comment: You have duplicate attributes in edittext and i cant set them for android studio 2.2.2

Comment: @mertaksu still 2 inputypes

Comment: android:minLength="6" - no such attribute in xml